# How to observe a json store in react?

Tags: reactjs, json, observable

I have this `Routes.json` file:

```
import Tickets from './Ticket/List';
import ViewTicket from './Ticket/View';

const routes = [
    {
        "path": "/",
        "component": Dashboard
    },
    {
        "path": "/tickets",
        "component": Tickets
    },
    {
        "path": "/ticket/view",
        "component": ViewTicket
    },
];

export default routes;
```

And using it, I have this dynamic routing component:

```
import routes from '../Routes.js';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFound from '../Panel/NotFound';

const MainRouting = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            {
                routes.map(route => {
                    const Component = route.component;
                    return <Route
                        key={route.path}
                        path={route.path}
                        element={<Component />}
                    />
                })
            }
            <Route
                path='*'
                element={<NotFound />}
            />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default MainRouting;
```

The problem is that, after running the app using `npm start` when I change the `Route.json` it won't be applied in my application in hot reload.

What should I do to make it observable, so that React would response to its changes?

Comment: React is a client library that runs in the browser. It cannot watch files on the server. Something like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) might be better for your case.

Comment: Then how comes when we change components, it hot-reloads? When do we change components `.js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx` files?

Comment: That is just a feature of WDS that is used in development mode.  It won’t work in production.

Comment: We never use hot-reload in production. I think noone does. I just want to have hot-reload for the state, that is stored inside a JSON file.

Comment: If you just want hot reload when that JSON file changes while in the development mode,  you can try to configure WDS so that it will watch that file.

Comment: I'm using CRA. I also use CRACO. I don't have direct access to WDS. But thank you for the comment.